# how framing byte packet to time length from android to python server?

Tags: android, python, sockets, fft

I'm trying to develop an application which send to pcm data to python server.

I used AudioRecord library to get real-time audio signal.

And this is the source code.

```
/*------ setting audio recording ------*/

private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private boolean isRecording = true;
private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private Thread recordingThread;
private AudioTrack player;
//byte[] TotalByteMessage;

/*------ about socket communication ------*/
public DatagramSocket socket;
private int port = 7979;
String IP = "192.168.0.4";



/*------ Recording, Playing and Sending packets method ------*/

private void startStreaming() {

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            try {
                /*------about socket------*/
                socket = new DatagramSocket();
                Log.d(LOG_NW, "Socket Created!");
                DatagramPacket packet;

                InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
                Log.d(LOG_NW, "Address retrieved!");


               /*------setting recording && playing------*/
                //get MinBufferSize for audio recording
                int Buffer_Size = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                        RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
                Log.d(LOG_Audio, "Min buffer size is " + Buffer_Size);

                if (Buffer_Size == AudioRecord.ERROR || Buffer_Size == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    Buffer_Size = SAMPLE_RATE * 2;
                }


                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION,
                        SAMPLE_RATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                        RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, Buffer_Size);

                if (recorder.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                    Log.d(LOG_Audio, "Audio Record can't initialize!");
                    return;
                }


                player = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                        RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, Buffer_Size,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                Log.d(LOG_Audio, "ready for playing music by using audiotrack");

                player.setPlaybackRate(SAMPLE_RATE);

                byte[] audioBuffer = new byte[Buffer_Size];
                Log.d(LOG_Audio, "AudioBuffer created of size " + Buffer_Size);

                recorder.startRecording();
                Log.d(LOG_Audio, "Start Recording!");

                player.play();
                Log.d(LOG_Audio, "Start Playing!");


                while (isRecording == true) {
                    //reading data from MIC into buffer
                    recorder.read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);
                    player.write(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);


                    //putting buffer in the packet
                    packet = new DatagramPacket(audioBuffer, audioBuffer.length, destination, port);

                    socket.send(packet);
                    Log.d(LOG_NW, "packet sending to  " + destination + " with port : " + port);

                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.d(LOG_Audio, "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(LOG_Audio, "IOException");
            }
        }
    }); // end of recordingThread

    recordingThread.start();
}
```

---

and this is the python server code.

```
import socket    
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

IP = "192.168.0.4"  
server_address = (IP, 7979)
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
buffer_size = 3584
server.bind(server_address)

i = True
while(i):
    print "Listening...\n"
    packet, client = server.recvfrom(buffer_size)
    #Convert packet to numpy array
    signal = np.fromstring(packet, dtype=np.int16)    
    i=False
server.close()
```

With this python code, I receive only one packet.

But later, I'll make a list to receive several packets.

I want to make a frame which has size of 64ms (time!) for windowing and FFT(Fast Fourier Transform), but the problem is a packet is 3584 bytes.

So I don't know how to windowing and do fft with byte packet from android in python server.

How can I make a frame using time length?

Comment: You have a packet of 3584 bytes. Why is the FFT a problem? Do you want the packet length to be a power of 2? And do you want to achieve that by padding and tapering? Is that what the windowing is about? Sorry for all those questions but I'm not sure what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now, I just received only one packet but I want to receive more packets to performing windowing and fft. the problem is i think I should have frame which has 64ms length, but i have a packet which has 3584 bytes length. so i don't know how to perform windowing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your while loop in your python code

```
i = True
while(i):
    print "Listening...\n"
    packet, client = server.recvfrom(buffer_size)

    #Convert packet to numpy array
    signal = np.fromstring(packet, dtype=np.int16)    

    i=False
server.close()
```

This will enter the loop, since `i == True`, then go through one iteration, and set `i = False` at the end of the first iteration, which will cause the loop to finish.

Comment: yes, i wanted to receive a packet. After modifying my code(receive packets continuously in list), and then, how can i slice the packet for 64ms??